Compatibility of SD-Card-Readers with iPads or iPhones
I have been using the set-up seen in the picture below for quite a while in order to use External-Storage with my iPad (Air, 3rd gen.). It's an Atolla USB-A-3.0-Hub [item 3 in the picture] which connects to the Apple Camera Adapter [item 5 in the picture] and thence to the iPad. When it's all connected up the Camera Adapter receives power from the Apple 12W (5.2V, 2.4A) power-supply [item 7 in the picture] and the hub receives power from its own 15W (5V, 3A) power-supply [item 1 in the picture].
The Lexar SD-Card-Reader I'm using in this way [item 2 in the picture] doesn't explicitly state on its packaging that it is compatible with iPads or iPhones (though it doesn't say anything to contrary either): it just states that the system requirements are "Mac OS 10.8+; Windows 10/8/7/Vista/XP; USB 2.0+ port", and I couldn't find anything further about it on Lexar's dysfunctional website. I have tested it and when doing so it seemed to work (reading and writing files with the iPad) without any problems in this set-up. Am I fine to keep doing this? Is there any reason why this SD-Card-Reader would not be compatible with iPhones and iPads besides the obvious physical USB-A-connection issue, which the set-up in the picture works-around?


Well, if it works, what exactly are you worried about?

The photo looks a little too 'CSI forensic' for my liking - always be aware of the background!

@Andy Griffiths I get a little crazy with things like this from time to time...


Is there any reason why this SD-Card-Reader would not be compatible with Iphones and Ipads besides the obvious physical USB-A-connection issue ...

Just because a product doesn't mention that it is compatible with ios / iPadOS devices, it doesn't necessarily mean that it is incompatible. If the product follows the correct specifications (for e.g. USB, file format, etc.) it can often work with these devices too. The reason for not mentioning it could be as obvious as the USB connector used. While you have found a convoluted way to connect the device to your iPad, someone who isn't as technically savvy as you will obviously be disappointed (and feel cheated) if they buy the device because it mentions it is iPad compatible, and then find they can't connect it directly to their iPad.
Sometimes manufacturers also don't mention compatibility as they may not want to deal handling customer support from the users of a particular device and / or invest more money - dealing with someone like Apple, buying new equipments, training, testing etc. all means increased cost.
For example, I am using a generic Chinese mouse that only mentions that it works fine with Windows. But I am able to use it without any issues on Windows, Mac and Linux.
With your setup, the only thing I'd be worried about is whether all the connections and power supplied to multiple devices may cause a problem in one or more of the connected devices.
You have a powered USB hub. That is good as it means it won't draw power from the device connected to it (in your case the Apple Camera Adapter). And if the USB hub is a good quality product, it will follow all the USB specifications and won't draw to much power or supply too much power to damage the devices connected to it. Your Apple Camera Adapter is also powered separately with an Apple power supply adapter. This too ensures that the Apple Camera Adapter will not unnecessarily draw any power from the iPad and work optimally.
All in all, I don't think you have anything to worry about (except the burden of lugging around all these multiple devices with your iPad).

Great. I see. Thank you. I had the Ipad modified to have a special sort-of box fitted to its rear (can't see it in the picture) into which all those peripherals tidy away nicely.

@william this question and what people can learn about USB and iPad plus iPhone hardware is just awesome.

@bmike Thanks! That's the first kind thing I've ever seen anyone say—let alone to myself—on this whole website.
